# Filtering messages from SNS to SQS Subscriptions on certain events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm pretty new to all this and I'm trying to create Subscription filter policies. Here's the general idea

S3 -> SNS Topic - > 3 different SQS: All Events, ObjectCreated, and ObjectRemoved.

I have all of these parts set up and the SQS have been subscribed to the one SNS topic, however, I can't get the SNS topic to filter out messages for the ObjectCreated and ObjectRemoved SQS's.

Can someone help me out? I know this is a pretty trivial problem but I haven't been able to deduce much even after using the AWS documentation on filtering

My code in the subscription filter policy for ObjectCreated Events:

```
{
    "Message": [
    "ObjectCreated"
     ]
}
```

message snippet:
[image: message snippet]

So far I've edited the subscription filter policy with the scope of "message body" with various versions of the code in image 1 (ObjectCreated Queue used in this case). Image 2 is the Message that is sent to my email / the All Events SQS that just takes all messages published by SNS without filtering anything.

Comment: Please do not post code nor errors as screenshot. Use properly formatted code blocks instead.

Comment: Apologies, first time on the site as well haha.

Comment: It's a good practice to mask your account I'd or any other easily identifiable information related to your AWS account.

Comment: Try using [Amazon SNS raw message delivery - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-large-payload-raw-message-delivery.html). It will make it easier to extract data from the message. At the moment, the messages are in a "string representation" within the `Message` field. Using Raw Delivery will put the message at the top-level instead of inside `Message`.

Comment: I've enabled raw message delivery. After this, what would the code within the Subscription filter policy look like? would the scope still be message body?